# Using multiple refs on a single React element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm using the `useHover()` react hook defined in [this recipe](https://usehooks.com/useHover/). The hook returns a `ref` and a boolean indicating whether the user is currently hovering over element identified by this `ref`. It can be used like this...

```
function App() {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();

  return (
    <div ref={hoverRef}>
      {isHovered ? 'Hovering' : 'Not Hovering'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now let's say that I want to use another (hypothetical) hook called `useDrag` which returns a `ref` and a boolean indicating whether the user is dragging the current element around the page. I want to use this on the same element as before like this...

```
function App() {
  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();
  const [dragRef, isDragging] = useDrag();

  return (
    <div ref={[hoverRef, dragRef]}>
      {isHovered ? 'Hovering' : 'Not Hovering'}
      {isDragging ? 'Dragging' : 'Not Dragging'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

This won't work because the `ref` prop can only accept a single reference object, not a list like in the example above.

How can I approach this problem so I can use multiple hooks like this on the same element? I found a [package](https://github.com/smooth-code/react-merge-refs) that looks like it might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Comment: Could you wrap the hoverRef in a dragRef component and [forward the hoverRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html) to a child element?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A React ref is really nothing but a container for some mutable data, stored as the `current` property. See the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs) for more details.

```
{
  current: ... // my ref content
}
```

---

Considering this, you should be able to sort this out by hand:

```
function App() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  const [hoverRef, isHovered] = useHover();
  const [dragRef, isDragging] = useDrag();

  useEffect(function() {
    hoverRef.current = myRef.current;
    dragRef.current = myRef.current;
  }, [myRef.current]);

  return (
    <div ref={myRef}>
      {isHovered ? 'Hovering' : 'Not Hovering'}
      {isDragging ? 'Dragging' : 'Not Dragging'}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Correct idea, but assigning to a ref won't cause a render, so `useEffect` will not get called properly. The assignment should happen in the callback instead.

Comment: Typescript doesn't like it.
```Cannot assign to 'current' because it is a read-only property.ts(2540)```

Answer (score 33):

A simple way to go about this is documented below.

Note: the `ref` attribute on elements takes a function and this function is later called with the element or node when available.

```js
function App() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div ref={myRef}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hence, `myRef` above is a function with definition

```js
function(element){
 // something done here
}
```

So a simple solution is like below

```js
function App() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  const anotherRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div ref={(el)=> {myRef(el); anotherRef(el);}}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The simple solution is what I needed. A TypeScript variation
`ref={((el: HTMLDivElement) => setNodeRef(el)) && ref}`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer @Hillsie, could I ask some link to some TypeScript documentation to understand that syntax? I've tried to understand it, specially the "&&", but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: @MiguelJara The TypeScript part is the `el: HTMLDivElement` the `&&` is a logical and shortcut. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: myRef is not a function`. Use `myRef.current = el` instead.

Comment: @holem `current` is a read-only property.

Comment: It is read-only because you are likely call `const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)` instead of `const myRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>()`. First returns `RefObject<T>` which is not mutable, second returns `MutableRefObject<T | undefined>` that allows you to mutate the value by using `myRef.current = el`. You can check the source code.

Comment: What works great? nothing in this answer or comments work. Is this an old React version?

Answer (score 13):

I use TypeScript and it doesn't let easily assign `.current` of refs created with `useRef` or forwarded ones (because it can be a `RefCallback` also). So I made a function that smartly merges all given refs into one `RefCallback` for clean/simple use. Check this out. Works great for me.

```
import { type MutableRefObject, type RefCallback } from 'react';

type MutableRefList<T> = Array<RefCallback<T> | MutableRefObject<T> | undefined | null>;

export function mergeRefs<T>(...refs: MutableRefList<T>): RefCallback<T> {
  return (val: T) => {
    setRef(val, ...refs);
  };
}

export function setRef<T>(val: T, ...refs: MutableRefList<T>): void {
  refs.forEach((ref) => {
    if (typeof ref === 'function') {
      ref(val);
    } else if (ref != null) {
      ref.current = val;
    }
  });
}
```

#### usage example

```
interface Props {
  // I pass it as a prop, you may use forwardRef - also supported by mergeRefs
  inputRef?: Ref<HTMLInputElement>;
}

export function Input({
  inputRef,
}: Props): ReactElement {
  // some local ref
  const privateRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      ref={mergeRefs(inputRef, privateRef)}
      // ... your other stuff
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: This didn't work with the ref-like value for useAutoAnimate from formkit.  The type of its ref is `(instance: Element | null) => void`.  It ended up causing an infinite loop in setRef above.  The accepted answer worked though.

Comment: Incredibly helpful answer and amazing solution. Hard to believe it works so well!

Answer (score 0):

Follwing what @Doc-Han is saying, if you ever need a reference AND also a form register for an input you can do something like this:

```
function App() {
  const myRef = useRef(null);
  const { register } = useForm({ defaultValues });

  const setRefs = useCallback((element) => {
    myRef.current = element;
    register({ required: 'First name is required.' })(element);
  }, [myRef, register]);

  return (
    <input ref={setRefs} />
  );
}
```