# How to add two refs in input? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm planning to set to autofocus the last element of the array by using a `ref`, but I don't know how to do it since I'm already using `ref` for [react-hook-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form)

I've been to this link, but I don't know how to apply it in my case. [How can I use multiple refs for an array of elements with hooks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54633690/how-can-i-use-multiple-refs-for-an-array-of-elements-with-hooks),

Somebody knows how to inject this two `ref`s to one input?

---

Here's my `ref` to  auto focus an `input`

```
const [inputRef, setInputRef] = useFocus();
```

And here's my current codes with *react-form-hook's ref*:

```
{[...Array(10)].map((x, i) => (
    <input
      type="text"
      name="book"
      className="border mr-px-5"
      ref={register(rules.book)}
      ref={lastElement ? inputRef : null} // conditional focus ref
    />
)}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple refs on a single React element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60270678/using-multiple-refs-on-a-single-react-element)

Comment: why do you need 2 refs ?? basically the ref is a reference to a dom element

Comment: so you want to focus an input on the happening of specific event then create a array of  every element then focus them as you need ... there is no need of 2 refs also You have `tabIndex` property

Comment: @Domi @JagadishLenka I updated the description. I forgot this is a multiple elements. and the `focus` ref should be conditional. The link you sent earlier can't help I think sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From frequent try and error, I finally found the solution. The `ref`s can actually use as function and then set two `ref`s in it.

And for the *react hook form* just pass the event on it to make it work also.

Here's the actual solution:

```
const [inputRef, setInputRef] = useFocus();

{[...Array(10)].map((x, i) => (
    <input
      type="text"
      name="book"
      className="border mr-px-5"
      ref={(event) => {
        register(event, rules.book);
        if (lastElement) inputRef.current = event;
      }}
    />
)}
```